# Real time show the max temperature outputed by sensors?

Tags: ubuntu, sensors

Is it possible to extract the maximum temperature from the output of `sensor`, and real time update it, and show it somewhere on desktop of Ubuntu 12.04?

I know psensor is to do that, but its version on 12.04 doesn't real time show the max temp on the panel (the top bar), although it does on the launcher.

Also I want to rely as less on GUI as possible, that is why I wonder if extracting the output of `sensors` is possible to do the above. But if it is not possible to real time show it somewhere on DE, is there other makeup solution?

```
$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +59.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
temp2:        +60.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        2990 RPM
temp1:        +59.0°C  
temp2:        +53.0°C  
temp3:        +41.0°C  
temp4:        +76.0°C  
temp5:        +36.0°C  
temp6:            N/A  
temp7:        +33.0°C  
temp8:            N/A  
temp9:        +43.0°C  
temp10:       +51.0°C  
temp11:       +49.0°C  
temp12:           N/A  
temp13:           N/A  
temp14:           N/A  
temp15:           N/A  
temp16:           N/A
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think of something like this:

```
watch -n0.1 "sensors | grep 'temp1\|temp2\|Core 0'"
```

Which would start outputting the temp1, temp2 and core 0 rows. With that maybe you can have like a small terminal on a corner or something, checking the information out.

You could also include information from `hddtemp` so you have both, CPU temp and HDD temp.